# FPDF: Decide when to set header/footer data

Tags: php, fpdf

I've been struggling with the header and footer data for quite some time now and thought it was time to ask it here on the forum.

What I'm trying to do is decide that if a page is added if the header / footer should be added or not. so code-wise I want to set the header/footer to on or off when adding a page.

I've tried to manipulate the function AddPage by setting an extra argument $setFooterHeader which default is set to true. And then trying to set this argument to false whenever I do an addPage('','',false); but it ignores it for some reason and I can't figure out why.

If I set the default value of the argument to false in the function itself it works like a charm, but when I try to do it in my script and set it as an argument, it totally ignores it.

Here's a code snippet of the fpdf.php file (function addPage)

```
function AddPage($orientation='', $size='', $setHeaderFooter=true) 
{ 
     // Start a new page 
     if($this->state==0) 
     $this->Open(); 
     $family = $this->FontFamily; 
     $style = $this->FontStyle.($this->underline ? 'U' : ''); 
     $fontsize = $this->FontSizePt; 
     $lw = $this->LineWidth; 
     $dc = $this->DrawColor; 
     $fc = $this->FillColor; 
     $tc = $this->TextColor; 
     $cf = $this->ColorFlag; 
     if($this->page>0) 
     { 
         // Page footer 
         if ($setHeaderFooter == true) 
         { 
             $this->InFooter = true; 
             $this->Footer(); 
             $this->InFooter = false; 
             // Close page 
             $this->_endpage(); 
         } 
      } 
     // Start new page 
     $this->_beginpage($orientation,$size,$setHeaderFooter); 
     // Set line cap style to square 
     $this->_out('2 J'); 
     // Set line width 
     $this->LineWidth = $lw; 
     $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F w',$lw*$this->k)); 
     // Set font 
     if($family) 
     $this->SetFont($family,$style,$fontsize); 
     // Set colors 
     $this->DrawColor = $dc; 
     if($dc!='0 G') 
     $this->_out($dc); 
     $this->FillColor = $fc; 
     if($fc!='0 g') 
     $this->_out($fc); 
     $this->TextColor = $tc; 
     $this->ColorFlag = $cf; 
     // Page header 
     if ($setHeaderFooter == true) 
     { 
         $this->InHeader = true; 
         $this->Header(); 
         $this->InHeader = false; 
     } 
     // Restore line width 
     if($this->LineWidth!=$lw) 
     { 
         $this->LineWidth = $lw; 
         $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F w',$lw*$this->k)); 
     } 
     // Restore font 
     if($family) 
     $this->SetFont($family,$style,$fontsize); 
     // Restore colors 
     if($this->DrawColor!=$dc) 
     { 
         $this->DrawColor = $dc; 
         $this->_out($dc); 
     } 
     if($this->FillColor!=$fc) 
     { 
         $this->FillColor = $fc; 
         $this->_out($fc); 
     } 
     $this->TextColor = $tc; 
     $this->ColorFlag = $cf; 
}
```

Below is a code snippet of my PHP script which uses FPDF

```
/** PHP FPDF */ 
require_once 'classes/FPDF/fpdf.php'; 
require_once 'classes/FPDI/fpdi.php'; 

class PDF extends FPDI 
{ 
     function Header() 
     { 
         $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 18 ); //set font to Arial, Bold, and 16 Size 

         //create heading with params 
         //0 - 100% width 
         //9 height 
         //"Page Heading" - With this text 
         //1 - border around it, and center aligned 
         //1 - Move pionter to new line after writing this heading 
         //'C' - center aligned 
         $this->Cell( 0, 9, 'Page Heading', 1, 1, 'C' ); 

         $this->ln( 5 ); 
     } 

     function Footer() 
     { 
         //move pionter at the bottom of the page 
         $this->SetY( -15 ); 

         //set font to Arial, Bold, size 10 
         $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 ); 

         //set font color to blue 
         $this->SetTextColor( 52, 98, 185 ); 

         $this->Cell( 0, 10, 'Footer Text', 0, 0, 'L' ); 

         //set font color to gray 
         $this->SetTextColor( 150, 150, 150 ); 

         //write Page No 
         $this->Cell( 0, 10, 'Page No: ' . $this->PageNo(), 0, 0, 'R' ); 
     } 
 } 

// Create new PDF object 
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); 
$pdf->addPage('','',false); 

// Output pdf file 
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','D');
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved this issue by setting a flag outside the class and use this flag in the header and footer function

The fix is in the page section, not in the addPage function

Just before doing an $pdf->addPage You set the flag as addPage automatically calls the header and footer function.

Here's the correct code (snippet of PHP script which uses FPDF)

```
/** PHP FPDF */ 
require_once 'classes/FPDF/fpdf.php'; 
require_once 'classes/FPDI/fpdi.php'; 

class PDF extends FPDI 
{ 
     function Header() 
     { 
        if ($this->header == 1)
        {
            $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 18 ); //set font to Arial, Bold, and 16 Size 

            //create heading with params 
            //0 - 100% width 
            //9 height 
            //"Page Heading" - With this text 
            //1 - border around it, and center aligned 
            //1 - Move pionter to new line after writing this heading 
            //'C' - center aligned 
            $this->Cell( 0, 9, 'Page Heading', 1, 1, 'C' ); 

            $this->ln( 5 ); 
        }
     } 

     function Footer() 
     {
        if ($this->footer == 1)
        {
             //move pionter at the bottom of the page 
             $this->SetY( -15 ); 

             //set font to Arial, Bold, size 10 
             $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 ); 

             //set font color to blue 
             $this->SetTextColor( 52, 98, 185 ); 

             $this->Cell( 0, 10, 'Footer Text', 0, 0, 'L' ); 

             //set font color to gray 
             $this->SetTextColor( 150, 150, 150 ); 

             //write Page No 
             $this->Cell( 0, 10, 'Page No: ' . $this->PageNo(), 0, 0, 'R' ); 
        }
     } 
 } 

// Create new PDF object 
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); 

$pdf->header = 0;
$pdf->footer = 0;
$pdf->addPage('','',false); 

// Output pdf file 
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','D');
```

Comment: I set this, but FOOTER is not working. When it is set to 0, it is still showing footer.

Comment: Very Intelligent!

Answer (score 6):

I know you found out the awnser already for yourself, but as one of the commenters pointed out this didn't work for me with the footer.

The good news is you can do without setting the external flags. You can use $this->PageNo() to determine whether to include the header and footer or not.

For instance if you'd want to exclude the header and footer on the first page, like I did:

```
function Footer() {
    if($this->PageNo() != 1){
          // footer code
    }
}
```

If you'd want to let's say exclude them on several pages and not write an endless if statement you should just put the page numbers to exclude in an array and check with in_array() whether the header and/or footer should be included.

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple different types of headers and footers by calling functions outside the class:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header(){
        if(!empty($this->enableheader))
            call_user_func($this->enableheader,$this);
    }
    function Footer(){
        if(!empty($this->enablefooter))
            call_user_func($this->enablefooter,$this);
    }
}


$pdf = new PDF('P');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Cell(50,6,'Headerless & Footerless page');



$pdf->enableheader = 'header1';
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->enablefooter = 'footer1';

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddPage();


$pdf->enableheader = 'header2';
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->enablefooter = 'footer2';

$pdf->Output();



function header1($pdf){
    $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Header type 1',1,0,'L');
}
function footer1($pdf){
    $pdf->SetY(280);
    $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Footer type 1',1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(0,6,"Page: {$pdf->PageNo()} of {nb}",1,0,'R');
}
function header2($pdf){
    $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Header type 2',1,0,'L');
}
function footer2($pdf){
    $pdf->SetY(280);
    $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Footer type 2',1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(0,6,"Page: {$pdf->PageNo()} of {nb}",1,0,'R');
}
```

The trick to footers is that the footer is added when the next page is created, with the last footer being added when the output is closed.
Therefore, you have to define the header before the page is added, and the footer afterwards but before the next page.